# How to repeat a command in python

Tags: python

I am just starting in python i want to make if the user wrote a number in the name he reapeats the question until he writes a string value and if he writes a the string value he asks him the number

```
while True :
    
      name = input("What is your name: ").capitalize()
      if any(char.isdigit() for char in name):
      print("Please do not include digits in your name.")     

 try:
   number = int(input("What is your number: "))
   break
 except ValueError:
    print(" you have to write a number")
```

Comment: on the name part you can use `continue` keyword to skip the iteration and start over if the value is wrong.

Comment: just as note,  you are probably better with a `for loop` or `while counter` so that after n tries the code exits with "too many errors".

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
while True :
    name = input("What is your name: ").capitalize()  # get input
    if any(char.isdigit() for char in name):  # check input
        print("Please do not include digits in your name.")
        continue # start over (skip iteration and start new iteration of loop)
    while True:  # loop for second input.
        number = input("What is your number: ")  # get input. 
        try:
            number = int(number)
            break  # stop the loop if input is a number.
        except ValueError:
            print(" you have to write a number")
            # if input is not a number. loop will run again (run next iteration)
    break  # when we got both inputs right. stop the main loop.
```